# File couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it error When presenting UIVideoEditorController

Tags: swift4.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hle1L.png)
I am recording video and using avfoundation and after that getting video url provide to UIVIdeoEditorController but  am getting error :**File couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it error When presenting UIVideoEditorController.**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't add the proper key and description to the Info.plist file to request permissions to access the camera